# API Connect in Bluemix intermittently result HTTP/500

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I have a published API in API Connect running in Bluemix Public. The API calls a loopback application which in turn performs a REST call to the backend. The loopback application, when runs locally runs fine, however when the API calls is performed through the API Connect Catalog in Bluemix; it intermittently generates a 500 error.

See [CURL errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4Ygp.png). As shown in the image, subsequent calls intermittently generates error 500. The loopback application does not have any trace of the failed calls.

Comment: The image seems to have been removed. Can you please add the CURL errors to the question so we can investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having these intermittent issues? These issues could happen when the Bluemix service is going through maintenance or is experiencing issues, which happens rarely. You can always check the status of services here:

UK: https://status.eu-gb.bluemix.net/

US: https://status.ng.bluemix.net/